# OpenCV QT VS2010 link error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv

As the title implies, I am using VS2010 with OpenCV 2.4.3 and QT 4.8. I tried running them independently (OpenCV+VS2010) and then (Qt+VS2010) and they worked fine. But when I try to run all three of them together in a single program, I get a linker error

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d244d.lib'
```

I tried looking around but doesn't seem to be able to find any solution. Could you please advice? Thank you.

Comment: "I am using VS2010 with OpenCV 2.4.3"  <--> "cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d244d.lib'"     do you spot the version mismatch here ?

Comment: oh bummer, got it fixed. I was using opencv 2.4.4 on VS2012 then changed to use OpenCV2.4.3 on VS2010 because apparently I can't use QT5 with VS2012 on windows 7. Thanks for pointing that out!